# Opening URL from watch on phone (Tizen)

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am developing a Tizen Web App for the Samsung Gear. (Using Tizen 2.4)

Currently I try to add a function which allows the user to open a link on his phone via the watch.
So when he presses a button, an URL will open in the phone's default browser. I noticed other smart watch apps have this functionality.

After browsing these forums, I found a code example:

```
var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view',
'https://www.tizen.org', null, null, null, null);

tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null, function() {
console.log('launch application control succeed');
}, function(e) {
console.log('launch application control failed. reason: ' + e.message);
}, null);
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the following error: `"launch application control failed. reason: No matched application found."`

My app does have the following privlige in it's config file added:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.info"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
```

1. Is this this the correct application to use to open a link on the phone's browser?
2. Are these all the required privileges for this feature?
3. Why is the application not found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it
You will need the application.launch privilege.

```
function openBrowserOnPhone(url) {
    var appid = "com.samsung.w-manager-service";
    var type = "phone";

    var extra_data = [
              new tizen.ApplicationControlData("msgId", ["mgr_install_host_app_req"]),
              new tizen.ApplicationControlData("type", [type]),
              new tizen.ApplicationControlData("deeplink", [url])];
    var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
               "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/default",
               null,
               null,
               null,
               extra_data);
    var appControlReplyCallback = {
            onsuccess: function(data) {
                console.log("launchUrl reply success");
                console.log("success: data = " + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            onfailure: function() {
                console.log("launchUrl reply failed");
            }
        };
    try {
        tizen.application.launchAppControl(
                 appControl,
                 appid,
                 function() { console.log("intentBorba", "launchUrl success"); },
                 function(err) { console.log("intentBorba", "launchUrl failed: " + err.message); },
                 appControlReplyCallback);
    }catch(err) {
        console.error("[launcher] " + err);
    }
}
```

Comment: You Sir, Made my day. Confirmed working on a Galaxy Active 2 Running Tizen 5.5